# push to new page within function react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react, and I am trying to push to a new page through a function. The function is `createCheckoutSession`... here's what I have.

```
export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (user == null) {
    this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
  }
```

how to I declare this.props, or how do I actually push the new page? It is logging error:

```
'props' is not defined      no-undef
```

here is my entire page.

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/auth";
import * as routes from '../routes';
import './checkout.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MyGifSpinner from './manageSubSpinner';
import './manageSubSpinner.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import myGif from '../pages/spinner';
import myGifSpinner from './manageSubSpinner';
import { doSignOut } from '../models/AuthorizationHome';
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const app = firebase.app();




    export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
      if (user == null) {
        this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
      }
    
      console.log(user)
    
      //price ID with trial LIVE ID
      var price = 'price_1IGW85KDPaWWeL1yjWsi9oRa'
    
      // var price = 'price_1Iav0JKDPaWWeL1yBa9F7Aht'
    
     firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid).collection('subscriptions').get().
     
      if (activtyStatus == "canceled") {
        console.log("sub is cancelled")
        //live price
        price = 'price_1IfmDsKDPaWWeL1ywjMTGarh'
        
      
      }
      
      console.log("activity status is: " + activtyStatus)
    
     
    
    
          const checkoutSessionRef = await firestore
          .collection('customers')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('checkout_sessions')
          .add({
            price: price,
            success_url: "http://localhost:3000/clients",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/signin",
        });
    
        
          // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
                checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(function (snap) {
                  const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
                  if (error) {
               
                  console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
                  return;
                }
                if (sessionId) {
                 
    
                
                
                const stripe = window.Stripe('pk');
                console.log("going to stripe: ")
                // this.setState({ isRegistering: true });
               
               console.log("line 116 checkout.js")
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: sessionId})
                console.log("logged stripe")
                
              }
          });
        }
```

it is basically a function to call stripe, and open the stripe checkout page in the new window. So I am trying to catch if the user == null, and if true, the push them to sign in page

Comment: is this a class or hook?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili to be honest, i'm not sure. I am still totally new to all this and am having trouble figuring it out

Comment: It looks like a hook and you cant use `this` with hooks. Can you post the full component for the page

Comment: @UdenduAbasili i've attached my entire page instead. please find above in the question

Answer (score 0):

As I have already said, you cant use `this` in a React function since it is stateless, so you need to useHistory. So you need to this to your code

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

 export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
  let history = useHistory();
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
      if (user == null) {
        history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
      }
...
```

Comment: oh I see, this makes sense actually. The only thing is, it gives the error `Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.`. how would i export useHistory?

Comment: have you installed the latest `react-router-dom` with `npm install react-router-dom` or `yarn add react-router-dom`

Comment: what is your react version?

Comment: react version is 17.0.2

Comment: Ok this is weird. `useHistory ` is a component of `react-router-dom` and that should work